# Count number of integers of a String then paste it into a new file - RStudio

Tags: r, string, parsing, integer

I want to work with a very big text file (txt) that contains more than 3 million lines, each line with a different name, containing characters and integers.

My idea is to clean a little bit this file (so I can use it easier) and remove those names that have more than 2 numbers.

I would like to parse the names, counting the numbers and then if the name contains less than 3 numbers, writing it into a new file in R.

My big file would be something like this (separating names in new lines):

> susan123 susan1 john john22345 alex55 alex1234

And then I would have this new file:

> susan1 john alex55

Is this possible in R?

Thanks

Comment: `cat(gsub('\\S*\\d{3,}\\S*\\s*', '', readLines('file.txt')), file = 'newfile.txt')`

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave reading and writing the file to your choice of functions. When you've got the words in R in a vector, here's a way to subset it to just the names with less than 3 digits.

```
x = c("susan123", "susan1", "john", "john22345", "alex55", "alex1234")

library(stringr)
x[str_detect(x, pattern = "\\D+\\d{0,2}$")]
# [1] "susan1" "john"   "alex55"
```

Comment: you are taking `x` to be a vector of words. in OP's question, OP has words in a file. Not in a vector of words

Comment: @Onyambu I'd suggest encouraging OP to clarify rather than criticizing answers making fair assumptions. OP says there are "separating names in new lines". Since they didn't ask for help reading in the data, I've assumed that's not an issue and they've successfully read in the data. It's trivial to modify this to work on a column of a dataframe instead of a vector.

Comment: In no way was i criticizing your answer. Was just pointing out to the fact that OP has a file. Maybe you could consider including that within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

We could use `which` with `nchar` and `gsub` and the `useNames = TRUE` argument of `which`:

```
x = c("susan123", "susan1", "john", "john22345", "alex55", "alex1234")

x[which(nchar(gsub("\\D", "", x)) < 3, useNames = TRUE)]
```

```
[1] "susan1" "john"   "alex55"
```

Comment: if you had a vector of words then `grep('^\\D*\\d{0,2}\\D*$', x, value = TRUE)` is enough. But OP does not have a vector of words. OP has words in a file

Comment: @Onyambu. Thank you for clarification. I took the example vector of Gregor Thomas!